AWS SDK V3 Lambda::InvokeCommand missing payload
This is about AWS SDK V3. The following code does not behave as expected:
import { 
    LambdaClient, 
    InvokeCommand,  
    LogType,
    InvocationType
} from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda";
const lambdaClient = new LambdaClient({});


const payload = { 
    "param1": 100, 
    "param2": 200
};

const input = {
    FunctionName: TAG + "data-iot",
    InvocationType: InvocationType.Event,
    LogType: LogType.Tail,
    // Payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    Payload: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload), "utf8")
};
let invokeCommand  = new InvokeCommand(input);
let res = await lambdaClient.send(invokeCommand);
console.log(`res = ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);

The output logs for this, the calling functions are:
res = 
{
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 202,
        "requestId": "b06b7abf-3bcb-42f3-b45d-c66c9c6badb0",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "Payload": {},
    "StatusCode": 202
}

The function which is being called does execute, but it has an empty payload! The first line in the lambda is console.log(event); Which gives us:
INFO {}

Any idea how I should be getting my payload in. I've tried just shoving a string in. And a json object. But the above appears to be what the docs ask for???

UPDATE
I've tested this same piece of invocation code (Used @aws-sdk/client-lambda version ^3.588.0)  against a NodeJS 20 Lambda function and I'm not getting any issues at all. Both param1 and param2 showed up on CloudWatch logs. Can you make sure that your function is:

Updated and properly deployed in the AWS console.
Are you sure you were invoking the function from the correct region?

Here is the SAM template I've used to define my function

  ApiHelloTester:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub "ac-playground-hello"
      CodeUri: dist/handlers/playground/hello
      Runtime: nodejs20.x
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref CoreApiGateway
            Path: /playground/hello
            Method: POST

and the CloudWatch logs that I've received.
2024-06-01T12:02:37.285Z    429098a7-7907-4b78-ac65-ca61cec88b2f    INFO    { param1: 100, param2: 200 }

Also, you are getting an empty response payload from the function you were invoking because you have configured the invocation type to InvocationType.Event which means that its asynchronous.

For asynchronous invocation, Lambda places the event in a queue and returns a success response without additional information.

In order to get a response programatically, you'll need to change the invocation type to InvocationType.RequestResponse.

The  primary issue is that the payload is not received by the lambda which has been invoked. The console.log(event) occurs at the very start of that lambda, showing that the event is empty!? You may well be 100% right that my efforts to log the response in the calling lambda would not have worked.

@monkey OK, let me try this in a bit. Tnx for clarifying the main issue. Could you share about the nature of the target function? Is it in Node? What was it trying to do, how much invocations is it getting per second?

Sure. All the lambdas are in node 18. It's currently in pre-production so only getting pinged about 100 times an hour. The purpose of this is actually to test the lambda function. A test suite runs independently, invoking the lambda and sends a few test values. Once these have been processed, the desired outcomes can be verified.

@monkey, tested it on my side and it works just fine. Are you aware of any SCP or IAM roles associated with your function that specify explicit denies to CloudWatch? If not, then we may not have enough information to replicate the challenge you were facing.

Hi. Thanks for thst. There's no issue with iam etc. The lambda is successfully run. It just doesn't recieve the payload. It works fine with aws sdk v2 so no question that under the hood it works in SAM or cloud formation. So you are using exactly the same aws sdk v3 code I posted??

So, I restarted my computer in desperation and ran the cdk deploy again. And now it works... It's not a satisfactory answer to why it didn't work before... I'm not sure what the lesson to take away from this is. The code was right in the first place.
